# What is the best way to calculate word frequency in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, hashtable, word-frequency

There are some good examples on how to calculate word frequencies in C#, but none of them are comprehensive and I really need one in VB.NET.

My current approach is limited to one word per frequency count. What is the best way to change this so that I can get a completely accurate word frequency listing?

```
wordFreq = New Hashtable()

Dim words As String() = Regex.Split(inputText, "(\W)")
    For i As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
        If words(i) <> "" Then
            Dim realWord As Boolean = True
            For j As Integer = 0 To words(i).Length - 1
                If Char.IsLetter(words(i).Chars(j)) = False Then
                    realWord = False
                End If
            Next j

            If realWord = True Then
                If wordFreq.Contains(words(i).ToLower()) Then
                    wordFreq(words(i).ToLower()) += 1
                Else
                    wordFreq.Add(words(i).ToLower, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

Me.wordCount = New SortedList

For Each de As DictionaryEntry In wordFreq
        If wordCount.ContainsKey(de.Value) = False Then
            wordCount.Add(de.Value, de.Key)
        End If
Next
```

I'd prefer an actual code snippet, but generic 'oh yeah...use this and run that' would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Class CountWords

    Public Function WordCount(ByVal str As String) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Dim ret As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        Dim word As String = ""
        Dim add As Boolean = True
        Dim ch As Char

        str = str.ToLower
        For index As Integer = 1 To str.Length - 1 Step index + 1
            ch = str(index)
            If Char.IsLetter(ch) Then
                add = True
                word += ch
            ElseIf add And word.Length Then
                If Not ret.ContainsKey(word) Then
                    ret(word) = 1
                Else
                    ret(word) += 1
                End If
                word = ""
            End If
        Next

        Return ret
    End Function

End Class
```

Then for a quick demo application, create a winforms app with one multiline textbox called InputBox, one listview called OutputList and one button called CountBtn. In the list view create two columns - "Word" and "Freq." Select the "details" list type. Add an event handler for CountBtn. Then use this code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem

Public Class MainForm

    Private WordCounts As CountWords = New CountWords

    Private Sub CountBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CountBtn.Click
        OutputList.Items.Clear()
        Dim ret As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = Me.WordCounts.WordCount(InputBox.Text)
        For Each item As String In ret.Keys
            Dim litem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
            litem.Text = item
            Dim csitem As ListViewSubItem = New ListViewSubItem(litem, ret.Item(item).ToString())

            litem.SubItems.Add(csitem)
            OutputList.Items.Add(litem)

            Word.Width = -1
            Freq.Width = -1
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

You did a terrible terrible thing to make me write this in VB and I will never forgive you.

:p

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Fixed blank string bug and case bug

Comment: index As Integer = 0 should be = 1, otherwise the first character of the first word is missed. Otherwise this is great, thanks. And congrats on 2,000 points!

Answer (score 3):

This might be what your looking for:

```
    Dim Words = "Hello World ))))) This is a test Hello World"
    Dim CountTheWords = From str In Words.Split(" ") _
                        Where Char.IsLetter(str) _
                        Group By str Into Count()
```

I have just tested it and it does work

EDIT! I have added code to make sure that it counts only letters and not symbols.

FYI: I found an article on how to use LINQ and target 2.0, its a feels bit dirty but it might help someone http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx

Comment: I'm using .net 2.0, so unfortuantely I can't use LINQ.

Comment: Awww that totally just stuff it all up.

Comment: It would have been so easy for you.

Comment: Use the new compiler and target 2.0 framework. Copy enumerable.cs from Mono, and presto.

Comment: I just found this, which may help:
http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

[Word frequency algorithm for natural language processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90580/word-frequency-algorithm-for-natural-language-processing)

Comment: I've already looked at that - everything either uses LINQ or isn't in .net

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close, but \w+ is a good regex to match with (matches word characters only).

```
Public Function CountWords(ByVal inputText as String) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim frequency As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    For Each wordMatch as Match in Regex.Match(inputText, "\w+")
        If frequency.ContainsKey(wordMatch.Value.ToLower()) Then
            frequency(wordMatch.Value.ToLower()) += 1
        Else
            frequency.Add(wordMatch.Value.ToLower(), 1)
        End If
    Next
    Return frequency
End Function
```

Comment: You and your fancy regular expressions. I just got back from writing a Lexer for one of my projects and was in the "lexing" mode there. Your solution is better though... Perhaps not as fast? I would have to do research. +1