# How to combine my python nlp solution for document ranking with solr for indexing?

Tags: python, solr, nlp, full-text-indexing

I'm new to NLP and Solr. I'm trying to build an application to rank past court case documents based on a newly given case document. I confused about how to use Solr for document indexing to speed up my processing time.

I have built a python solution including Preprocessing with NLTK library and lemmatization with Spacy library. And I have calculated document similarity with Word2Vec Word Embedding Model.

I'm stuck in the middle and am confused about whether I have done correctly. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: So what is your goal by introducing Solr to the mix?

Comment: I'm trying to index my documents to speed up the process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2956962/11185766 check this one

Comment: @SmirithikaChandrasegar
there are a bunch of ways to do this task. there is a tool called Milvus it's good for embedding search. I'm mentioning this because you mentioned you have the embedding. There is no use with embedding in solr as far as I know
https://milvus.io/docs/v0.10.6/example_code.md